# How was the Doctor able to reach into the 'crack in time' without being erased?

Tags: doctor-who

I just watched Cold Blood. Poor Rory was erased. But how was the Doctor able to reach into the light, into the crack, without himself getting unwritten? Because in the Flesh and Stone, he mentioned that he would be an excellent thing to feed to the Crack.

I've only watched up to Cold Blood, so no spoilers, please.

Comment: Note that the duplicate answer contains mild spoilers for the remainder of the season and you are advised to read with caution.